# Blog post - single.php url

Tags: urls, blog, single

I have a simple blog page that just lists blog posts on a page called 'news'

http://my-site.co.uk/news

I have a single.php page to display the actual post when it is clicked on 'news'

The single.php displays the post but the url is http://my-site.co.uk/the-post-title.

Is this normal or should it be http://my-site.co.uk/news/the-post-title

How cam I get it to be http://my-site.co.uk/news/the-post-title

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

You probably have your Permalinks set to "Post Name".

You can change your Permalinks to "Custom Structure" and put '/news' in there before the post title, so the "Custom Structure" field would look like this:

```
/news/%postname%/
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use custom post types if you want to have different posts permalinks like /news/post_title , /blog/post_title etc.